# How to handle categorical features in neural network?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am currently having a dataset for the location of stores and name of item to predict sales of a particular product.

I wanted to use binary encoding or pandas get_dummies(), but there are 5000 names for items and it causes memory error, is there any alternative or better way to handle this? Thanks all!

```
print(train.shape)
print(train.dtypes)
print(train.head())

(125497040, 6)
id               int64
date            object
store_nbr        int64
item_nbr         int64
unit_sales     float64
onpromotion     object
dtype: object
   id        date  store_nbr  item_nbr  unit_sales onpromotion
0   0  2013-01-01         25    103665         7.0         NaN
1   1  2013-01-01         25    105574         1.0         NaN
2   2  2013-01-01         25    105575         2.0         NaN
3   3  2013-01-01         25    108079         1.0         NaN
4   4  2013-01-01         25    108701         1.0         NaN
```

Comment: Whats the length of the dataframe

Comment: The length is about 100,000,000.

Comment: You need to go for parallel programming. A 100 million rows? Thats way too much to process

Comment: Can you add a sample of how your data looks. So we can think about scikit vectorizers

Comment: I mean to say atleast put the first 5 rows. `print(df.head(5))` in your question.

Comment: There are about 5000 unique item_nbr and 50 store_nbr. Thanks! Bharath

Comment: Is date a  important feature ?

Comment: They keyword here is **sparse**. Either use pandas sparsity-features (not sure how good they are; ```sparse=True```) or sklearn's (sparse on by default). If there are 5000 categories you will add 5000 columns, but only one of these in each row is non-zero. That's the whole idea of sparse data-structures (make sure the solver can exploit this).

Comment: My first thought for `scikit HashVectorizer` to get the sparse matrix not sure of 100,000,000 rows

Comment: @Bharathshetty I’ll try it and let you know! Thanks Bharat and sadcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating gazillions of dummy variables you should use one-hot encoding instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot

Pandas doesn't have this functionality built-in, so the easiest way is to use `scikit-learn`: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<... 'numpy.float64'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> enc.n_values_
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> enc.feature_indices_
array([0, 2, 5, 9])
>>> enc.transform([[0, 1, 1]]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: There is about a 100 million rows in a dataframe. Dont know it can stop memory error.

Comment: If I am using it to create an one hot encoded array, what the shape of tensor should look like? Thanks!

Comment: _"Pandas doesn't have this functionality built-in"_  ...`pd.get_dummies`?

Comment: pd.get_dummies produces... well, dummies. Lots of colums with 0s and 1s. One-hot encoding produces single value, which you can treat as a number or as an array of bits.

Comment: No, one-hot encoded variables is the other name for dummy. The output is an array in which only 1 column is active (hot) and all other contains 0. The pd.get_dummies and OneHotEncoder.transform() will produce exact same result (just that OneHotEncoder will work on numerical data and get_dummies on any type).

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you could:

1. Not to use all items but only most frequent ones.

   This way creating dummies, creates fewer new columns and needs less memory. For this happen you will need items with few counts (define few with a threshold) and you will lose some information.
2. An alternative approach will be to use a Factorization Machine.

You could use both suggestions above and at the end average their prediction for an even better score.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I cannot remove any columns because I have to predict all items.I will try FM and compare it to a NN too. Thanks!